# Kiel oni povas diri la anglan idiomaĵon "touchy-feely" nature esperante?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Kiel oni povas diri la anglan idiomaĵon "touchy-feely" nature esperante? La signifo estas ion similan kiel "havi tendencon esprimi emocion per tuŝo", ekzemple iu kiu brakumas aliajn homojn multe kaj povas esti tro emocia. Kvankam mi ne certas ke "tuŝema" aŭ "tro emocia" havas la ĝustan nuancon - homo kiu estas "touchy-feely" ofte havas tro da empatio kaj rezulte povas agaci aliulojn.

Comment: Leginte vian priskribon denove, mi pensas ke `tuŝema` estas bone priskriba.

Answer (score 1):

Kvankam por mi via proponita adejtktivo `tuŝema` estas ĝusta kaj neŭtra, oni povus ankaŭ uzi `karesema`, kiu estas ĉefe pozitiva, kune kun `tro`.

```
tro karesema
```

[*kares/i](https://vortaro.net/#karesi_kd): Delikate tuŝi, por montri al iu sian amon, amikecon, respekton ktp

Answer (score 0):

Mi eble dirus «emocidemonstrema» aŭ eble «pertuŝemociulo». Mi, persone, uzus malsaman vorton ĉar la esprimo «Touchy-Feely» estas iomete tro nuanca por Esperanto, laŭ mi.

Comment: Ne nur por Esperanto estas malfacile. En mia denaska mi ne scius kiel tion diri, eble ĉar ĉe ni korpa tuŝeto estas kulture normala afero dum interago.

Answer (score 0):

> korplingva / korpoproksima / sendistanca / tuŝdistanca [sociala distanco]

Mi ankaŭ pensis pri *fizika* tamen tie estas tro ampleksa. Kaj *tuŝema* certe kongruas kun *touchy-feely* sed eble estus tro negativa por distancitaj homoj.

Mi komprenas ke temas pri malgranda **sociala distanco**, kiel por brakumado.
Memorigas min pri iu proksimeculino, sampensionanino, kiu traktis min, fremdan viron, kiel ŝi traktus aliajn virinojn, per brakumado. Etna trajto eble.